# appending element and removing it destroys all event handlers in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok I create element, assign click handler, and append it to body. Then i remove it and reappend it and click handler is no longer working???

Why would this happen.

```
var btn = $('<button>').text('hi').click(function(){console.log(3);});
var div = $('<div>');
div.append(btn);
$('body').append(div);
//click it now, it works..
div.html('');
div.append(btn);
// now button doesn't work..
```

So why is this happening and what can i do to fix it.

Comment: don't know exactly, but could it be its because you do not close the div tag . and i have never seen a jQuery selector with <> like you have

Comment: @TimotheusTriebl `<*>` is not a selector, it's used by jQuery for a creating corresponding DOM elements.

Answer (score 10):

Since `.html('')` is essentially the same as [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/), the following applies (from the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)):

> To avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from the child elements before removing the elements themselves.
>
> If you want to remove elements without destroying their data or event handlers (so they can be re-added later), use `.detach()` instead.

One option would be to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). In doing so, the event isn't bound directly to the `button` element, it is bound to a constant parent element that isn't removed.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hs1qdo27/)

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
    // ..
});
```

---

As mentioned above, another option would be to use the [`.detach()` method](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) in order to remove the element from the DOM, without removing attached event listeners.

> The [`.detach()` method](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) is the same as `.remove()`, except that `.detach()` keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nbcxc1fr/)

```
div.find('button').detach();
div.append(btn);
```

Comment: yep this is better :) nice one and the explanation also

Comment: i feel this isn't modular....basically i've been trying to learn design patterns, specifically MVC.. I have yet to see it's benefit..i'm starting to think not all apps benefit from it though

Comment: @MuhammadUmer How exactly is it not modular?

Comment: i was referring to first part, but it's fine i guess.

Answer (score 2):

put this after the second div.append(btn); - > `btn = $('button').text('hi').click(function(){console.log(3);});`

Comment: this works however, doing this for multiple items i will have to make a function which would reattach all events. However, i was wondering if it was possible to just tell jquery to not destroy all events.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you're calling `html()` on the DIV that contains the button.

When you call `html()` with an empty string, it calls `empty()` internally.
Calling `empty()` on an element iterates over all the elements inside that element removing all data and events securely.

It does this by calling `jQuery.cleanData` on the button, which again explicitly calls `jQuery.removeEvent`, removing all events on the button.

The button is still stored in the variable `btn`, so it can be appended again, but it has lost all data and any events attached to it because the parent element had `html("")` called on it.

The solution is to use `detach()` to remove the element with all the data and events intact, so it can be appended again, or you can attach the event to a parent element that isn't removed, or you could just hide the element, generally there's no reason to remove the element just to reappend it, it's better to hide it.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/r6zthL4k/)

Answer (score 2):

This is very interesting situation. What happens when you clear `div` with `html('')` method. Take a look at [source code](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.html) and you will see that internally jQuery calls `jQuery.cleanData(getAll(elem, false));`. This method is responsible for removing all the related `data` for all child elements that have already been removed. This is important in order to avoid memory leaks.

Clearing data also removes events bound with `on` (and similar) methods, because those event handlers are also stored in internal cache object.

So as the result, even though you removed content of the `div`, the `btn` object is still in memory, but the event bound to it previously is gone.

This was the explanation of the problem. The solution is to use dedicated method called [`detach`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/). It will remove button from the DOM but will keep event data in case element will later be appended again.

```
// remove element but keep its data
btn.detach();

// append back
div.append(btn);
```

In situations like this you should not use `html('')`.